# Graphing functions and identifying their Laplace transforms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In each of the following cases, graph the function and find its Laplace transform:

(a) $f(x)=u(x-a)$ where $a$ is a positive number and $u(x)$ is the unit step function defined by 
$u(x)=0 $ if $ x<0$ or $u(x)=1$ if $x\ge0$

(b) $f(x)=[x]$ where $[x]$ denotes the greatest integer $\le x$

(c)$f(x)=x-[x]$

(d)$f(x)=\sin(x) $ if $0\le x \le \pi$ or $f(x)=0$ if $x\ge \pi$

I am really unsure how to attempt this problem and would really appreciate help.

Comment: Can you tell us what you know about Laplace transforms? Is that the part you're stuck on, or is graphing the functions also a problem?

Comment: I am primarily stuck on the graphing portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) First let's choose an arbitrary $a>0$. for every $x<a$, you have $x-a<0$, and for every $x\ge a$ you have $x-a\ge 0$. Now you need to plot $u(x-a)$. This is a straight line along the horizontal axis up until $x=a$, then another horizontal line at $y=1$ starting at $a$ and towards $\infty$.

(b)$[x]$ is $0$ in the interval $[0,1)$ then it is $1$ in the interval $[1,2)$ and so on. This looks like a staircase increasing towards right. Do not plot the vertical pieces, like, for example the line between $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

(c)You repeat the same procedure as in part (b) you should get a saw-tooth like pattern

(d) Start plotting $\sin(x)$. Start from $0$. When your $y$ coordinate is $0$ again, you reached $x=\pi$. From there it's a horizontal line